Guidelines for reviews of published work
I have written several reviews of already published articles over the years, especially for AMS Math Reviews, but only recently I had the thought that unlike for a refereeing job (that is anonymous), the name of the reviewer is published for a review. So I think it should be OK for me to contact the author of the article if I need some help understanding it. But I am not sure. Is there any reason why I should not do it? Thanks for any insight.

This question should be posted on Academia Stack Exchange (https://academia.stackexchange.com/). Voting to close for this reason.

It is perfectly fine, and very common.
